# Sitecore GetCustomPropertyNames doesn't return all available field names for custom profile

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to build a form that will copy values from one field to another for a set of user's profiles. I have checked that all users have the same profile assigned (by checking the profile ID with user.Profile.ProfileItemId and I also checked the same thing in the User Manager tool, for some of the users).
Before moving a value from one field to another I want to check that the inputted field names actually exist for the current user's profile, so I'm calling GetCustomPropertyNames for each user's profile and checking whether the field name is present in the list of field names returned by the method.
I have noticed that for some users not all of the field names are returned. The missing fields are listed in the User Details dialog box with no value (empty fields). Adding values for fields not listed or clearing fields that are listed does not seem to alter the result of the GetCustomPropertyNames method.
Is there any special command that must be executed beforehand, or are there any special conditions that must be met in order to determine the method to return the entire set of available field names?

Comment: Did you try to see if the fields are in Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetPropertyValue("property")?

Comment: @xoail I'm not working with the context user, but iterating over a set of users belonging to a particular domain. However, I have tried your suggested method and for the users that have issues with GetCustomPropertyNames it raises a PropertyNotFound exception. However, I have tried it for custom fields that are returned by GetCustomPropertyNames and I get the same result. It seems to only return values for properties of the UserProfile class.

Comment: Take a look at this article (http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2012/10/Working-with-User-Options-in-the-Sitecore-Client.aspx) if you have not already. It talk about working with sitecore client but it helped in troubleshooting a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to do it like :

```
var userList = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers();


foreach (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user in userList)
{
    Sitecore.Security.UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
    string whatever = profile["Field Name"];

}
```

The ASP.NET profile is used to store and retrieve user settings in a data source such as a database. The user profile is accessed using the Profile property of the current HttpContext. Profile information and property values are managed using a profile provider.
The SqlProfileProvider (that is used default by Sitecore) is used by ASP.NET to store and retrieve profile settings for an ASP.NET application that is using a SQL Server database.

Comment: That seems to have the same result as user.Profile.GetCustomProperty(destinationProperty), it returns an empty string. I want to be able to verify whether the user's profile has the property, or not before trying to set it.

Comment: On User Manager are you seeing custom properties? Do you have a new user profile, and user are inheriting this profile?

Comment: Yes, I have a profile called CustomUser with some additional fields. I checked that all users inherit that profile. I can see the custom properties in the User Manager (or, to be more precise, the "Profile" tab in the "Edit user" dialog form.

Comment: Hmm it's really strange, I checked on my solution and it's working as expected,I suggest you to ask Sitecore Support about this issue.

Comment: Thank you for checking, but what do you mean by "as expected" ? As I said in my first comment, profile["field name"] returns the same result as profile.GetCustomProperty("field name"). In other words if it finds the field then it returns its value, and if it doesn't then it returns an empty string. This behavior is ambiguous since it could find a field and its value could be set to the empty string. I need to be able to differentiate between finding a custom field that has an empty string as its value and not finding a field at all, that's why I'm using profile.GetCustomPropertyNames().

Comment: Was profile["Field Name"] supposed to work different than described in the comment above?

Comment: I tried both version , profile["Field Name"] and your version and it worked both,they are getting results real results not empty string. Also can be a security problem, can you add using SecurityDisabler() before you call profile["field name"]

Comment: If you didn't resolve your issue, I see others have same issue like you: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=58551